# Move to next EditText when focused on EditText with maxlength

Tags: android

I'm trying to make the next `EditText` get the focus upon reaching the first `EditText` maxlength by adding a `TextWatcher` on the first edit text and call `editText2.requestFocus()` on `TextChanged`.

Now the problem happened when I try to gain focus on `editText1` which already reached the maxlength. When I try to key in any character it won't focus to `editText2` as the `TextWatcher` won't fire anymore.

Has anyone tried a fix on this? Note that as much as possible I want to keep the maxlength detail on my layout XML so the code won't get messed up.

Comment: Could you post some sample code?

Comment: Sorry, I can't right now. But you can see samples on moving the focus to next view using textwatcher here and that's just exactly what I did. Just add the maxlength to make things more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Here try this,
I assume max length is 5, you can set any number you want.

```
EditText editText1 = findViewById(R.id.et1);
final EditText editText2 = findViewById(R.id.et2);

        editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.toString().length() == 5){
                    editText2.requestFocus();
                }

            }
        });
```